# Funciones flechas y argumentos

Tags: javascript

Estoy aprendiendo JavaScript y resolviendo algunos ejercicios, hasta el momento se usar de forma básica las funciones flechas, me parecen muy interesantes, pero me surgió una duda.

Me di cuenta que existen funciones en las cuales se les puede agregar un `arrow function`, un ejemplo es este:

```
const resultado=cursos.filter(curso=>curso.tecnologia===input.tecnologia);
```

Hasta ahí todo bien, yo reconozco las funciones flecha de la esta manera:

```
const hola = () => { codigo }
```

Entiendo que `()` es para recibir parámetros, pero no me queda claro, el cómo es que se puede meter dentro de una función, dentro de otra; en este caso `.filter()` la siguiente

> arrow function .filter(curso=>curso.tecnologia

No me queda claro. Creo entender que *curso*, va ser una nueva función, pero no se si se puedan crear funciones sin guardarlas en variables antes, también porque *curso=>* se apunta a sí misma, no me queda claro, `curso=>curso.tecnlogia`, espero puedan ayudarme a comprender, gracias

Comment: En este video https://youtu.be/3eLx9syx8iI explican todo lo que tienes dudas, incluso te dicen como hacer tu mismo una funcion map, filter, etc...y el tipo es muy simpatico explicando, jaja

Comment: En el caso que expones, el método `filter()` espera recibir como parámetro una función de retorno o [callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Callback_function), que es lo que deberías investigar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voy a hacer mi mejor esfuerzo por explicarlo.

Lo primero que hay que entender es que se pueden pasar funciones como parámetro a otras funciones. Por ejemplo:

```js
//Declaramos una función que imprime un texto en la pantalla
function foo(){
    console.log('Hola')
}

//Creamos una función que recibe otra función como parámetro y la ejecuta
function Ejecutar(funcion){
    funcion()
}

//Llamamos a la función Ejecutar, pasándole foo como parámetro
Ejecutar(foo)
```

También podríamos crear una función flecha y guardarla en una variable llamada `foo` y obtendríamos el mismo resultado:

```js
//Guardamos la función en una variable llamada foo
const foo = () => {
    console.log('Hola')
}

//Creamos una función que recibe otra función como parámetro y la ejecuta
function Ejecutar(funcion){
    funcion()
}

//Llamamos a la función Ejecutar, pasándole foo como parámetro
Ejecutar(foo)
```

Lo segundo que hay que entender es que existen las funciones anónimas. Estas son funciones sin nombre. Pueden usar la sintaxis de `function` o la sintaxis flecha. Por ejemplo:

```
function(){
    console.log('Hola')
}

//o

() => { console.log('Hola') }
```

En este ejemplo vamos a pasarle una función anónima a la función `Ejecutar`:

```js
//Creamos una función que recibe otra función como parámetro y la ejecuta
function Ejecutar(funcion){
    funcion()
}

//Llamamos a la función Ejecutar, pasándole una función anónima
Ejecutar( () => { console.log('Soy una función anónima') } )
```

Finalmente un ejemplo un poco más complejo, donde la función anónima recibe parámetros:

```js
function Ejecutar(funcion){
    //Ejecutamos funcion, pasándole 1 y 2 como parámetros
    funcion(1, 2)
}

Ejecutar( (a, b) => { console.log(a + b) } )
```